# Hash Function Determination

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

How can we find the most efficient hash function(least possible chances of collision) for the set of strings.

Suppose we are given with some strings.. And the length of the strings is also not defined.
Ajay
Vijay
Rakhi
....

we know the count of no. of strings available, so we can design a hash table of size(count available). what could be the perfect hash function that we could design for such problem??

Multiplying each character ascii value by 31(prime no.) in increment fashion leads to the a hash value greater than the value of MAX_INT, and then modulus would not work properly... So please give some efficient hash function build up solution....

I have few set of strings,, lets say count = 10.... I need to implement a hash function such that all those 10 strings fit in uniquely in the hash table.... Any perfect hash function O(1) available, for this kind of problem?? hash table size will be 10, for this case...

Only C Programming...

Please explain the logic at website.... http://burtleburtle.net/bob/c/perfect.c
This looks very complicated but perfect to me..!! what is the algorithm used here... Reading the code straight away, is very difficult!!

Thanks....

Comment: Ohh these solutions are of no help dear.... Does there any solution exists which could give a perfect hash value for given set of strings...  no of strings could be very large.... Perfect Hash Solution!! Does it at all exists..?

Comment: The gperf program recommended by @Necrolis is an actual working open-source program. You can download and view the source to see how it's done. It's hard to imagine a better example than that.

Comment: And what about the code on this website...

Comment: http://burtleburtle.net/bob/c/perfect.c this website looks good.. perfect hash function... but i am not able to understand it.. please help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look into [perfect hashing.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hashing)

Comment: Philip,, can you support this with an example... if we have strings... how can we get an integer(unique) out of those list of stringss??

Comment: @AGeek: If you look at the "External Links" section of the article that Philipp linked, you'll see several free implementations of perfect hash generators.

Comment: I need a code.... examplee... in C program... and need a perfect hash function.. that could give the result in O(1) time..

Answer (score 17):

Check some of these out, they apparantly have good distributions

http://www.partow.net/programming/hashfunctions/#HashingMethodologies

Answer (score 2):

you might want to have a look at [gperf](http://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/), you could kinda do this on the fly if you didn't do it too often and your data set a small. if the strings are know ahead of time, then this is *the* method

Answer (score 0):

Hash tables are meant to be able to handle dynamic input.  If you can guarantee only a particular set of inputs, and you want to guarantee a particular slot for each input, why hash at all?

Just make an array indexed for each known available input.

Comment: For a large data-set with almost only read-access, it can be sensible to use something like perfect hashing.

Comment: Why would it make sense to hash when you have a known set of inputs and are guaranteeing a slot for each input?  You could just skip the cost of a hash function and do an array lookup with #defined indexes for each "known input".

Comment: "known input" is relative. If you know you will be doing random access to 5GiB of data *that is supplied at runtime*, it might be a good idea to perfectly hash it first to get O(1) access.

Comment: There's still the matter of turning a string into an integer so that you can look it up in a table. How do you propose to use a string as an array index?

Comment: @Jim, Good point.  Phillip's comments are valid to.  I've seen that the question's been altered a bit to not account for complete knowledge of each input, so no my answer seems very irrelevant.